# Text sticks to the top of the its tag

Tags: html, css

Text on the image below sticks to the top of the container (blue) for some reason.

[image]

I want it to be on the same line as the logo.

**CSS:**

```
.Header {
  background-color: rgb(173, 181, 189);
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  height: 9.6rem;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
}

.Wrapper {
    align-content: center;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.Logo {
    height: 3.2rem;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 3.2rem 0.5rem 3.2rem 3.2rem;
    position: relative;
    width: 3.2rem;
}

.Title {
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 3.2rem;
    font-family: Verdana;
    height: auto;
    margin: 3.2rem 0 3.2rem 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<header className={css.Header}>
    <div className={css.Wrapper}>
        <img src={logo} className={css.Logo} alt="logo" />
        <h1 className={css.Title}>List of Participants</h1>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `align-self: center` solves the issue.

```
.Title {
    align-self: center;
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 3.2rem;
    font-family: Verdana;
    height: auto;
    margin: 3.2rem 0 3.2rem 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```